# В скором времени или в ближайшем будущем?

Tags: стилистика

Набрел на такую вот фразу (фамилия заменена экземплификантом):

***Отставка Имярекова в любом случае состоится – вопрос лишь в том, когда это произойдет: в скором времени или в ближайшем будущем.***

Интересно, что наступит раньше: "ближайшее будущее" или "скорое время".
А если серьезно, как называется такой тип речевой ошибки?
Или я придираюсь и такая конструкция имеет право на существование?

*Кстати, мне кажется, что тут и с пунктуацией не все в порядке, тире сомнительно, но это уже для бонусного обсуждения.*

(+) Поскольку понятие речевой ошибки оказалось не для всех очевидным, то уточню, что выбирать для начала надо из множеств лексических и стилистических ошибок. Хотя... Короче, не буду подсказывать, коли сам не уверен.

Comment: На существование конечно имеет право. Типа там авторский смысл и все такое. Но с логикой тут не в порядке. Это как в анекдоте: ты дурак или ты дурак. Можно назвать эту ошибку отсутствием альтернативности союза "или", противоречащей его назначению

Comment: @user190920 спасибо, но мне бы хотелось более содержательного ответа. В частности, ссылки на "авторский смысл" тут не проходят.. И я не спрашиваю, "как можно назвать" этот тип ошибки, я интересуюсь, как он называется, все известные ошибки давно перечислены и расклассифицированы, термина "отсутсутвие альтернативности" в том списке нет

Comment: А где посмотреть на тот список и классификацию ошибок? Можете дать ссылку?

Comment: Ну если не претендуете на академичность, то хотя бы тут: https://4brain.ru/blog/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B/

Comment: А более серьезный уровень - это к Розенталю, "Литературная правка"  и прочие его труды.

Comment: Плеоназмом можно назвать, его подвидом — периссологией, чрезмерным излишеством слов в речи; ненужной растянутостью речи и т. д. Конкретный случай тянет на «парный П.».

http://odiplom.ru/lab/pleonazm.html

Comment: @shampar *парный плеоназм* - в этом сочетании я не очень понимаю слово "парный", но боюсь, в нашем случае вся конструкция на плеоназм вообще не тянет. Автор недвусмысленно **противопоставляет**  синонимичные понятия, плеоназмам такое не свойственно.

Answer (score 1):

Само по себе противопоставление синонимов не является речевой ошибкой (http://www.fio.ru/pravila/leksika/ispolzovanie-sinonimov-v-rechi/ *Возможно даже противопоставление синонимов, имеющих значительные **отличия** в смысловой структуре или в стилистической окраске* [не смеялся, а хохотал]). Если же в авторской риторике заложено неверное представление о соотношении *значений* двух фразеологизмов (напр. здесь о разной длительности временных промежутков: совсем короткий и более длинный), то ошибка *лексическая*. Однако в данном примере можно усмотреть и легкую авторскую *иронию*: это похоже на известную шутку (если от насморка лечиться, он проходит через неделю, а если не лечиться, то через 7 дней).

Comment: *Если же в авторской риторике заложено неверное представление о соотношении значений двух фразеологизмов... то ошибка лексическая.* - полагаю, что так и есть. Но какого типа? Понимаете, если автор просто путает значения некорректно разделяя абсолютный синонимы, то это скорее семантическая ошибка. Так что вопрос не снимается.  Что же до остальных ваших предположений (ирония и противопоставление), то я не могу подобного углядеть. Мне не хочется весь текст приводить - он подчеркнуто политический, но нет там такого. Поверьте.

Comment: *Поверьте* — я верю легко. Бывают такие "умники": говорят с умным видом красивые с виду фразы, надеясь произвести впечатление и веря, что таких их ляпов не заметят или даже сочтут за красноречие.